# Binding data to ListView doesn't work (Metro UI)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

When I put this code into my XAML file:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" Margin="15,0,0,0" />
```

It shows me `Name` value but when I try show it via `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemListView"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
      Margin="60,0,0,10">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  
                       FontSize="24" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" 
                       FontSize="16" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

It doesn't show up :( What could be wrong?

Comment: Does the Items binding that you are using expose objects that have a Name and Artist property on them?

Comment: can you give details on the list of items?  How do you set the datacontext?  What is the type of the list?  What are the objects it is holding?

Comment: +1 on Josh questions. We can't tell anything from your example. How did the first binding work? Did you set the `TextBlock`'s parent `DataContext` to `{Binding Items}`?

Answer (score 0):

If the page inherits from LayoutAwarePage, like it will by default when created from a template, the DataContext will be set to a property named DefaultViewModel.  Properties exposed in your codebehind will not be bound to.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at two different objects in the sample. In the textbox you are looking at the Name of the object in the datacontext, in the listview you are looking at the Items[x].Name for each item you bind to. If you need to reference the Name from the datacontext rather than the Items collection you will need to bind the source to an Element not inherit it.